# Change multiple pairs of lines to single lines?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to print/echo or redirect below lines into some file

```
phone: "3434343"
name: "jack"

phone: "9876735"
name: "john"

phone: "3434343"
name: "Mack"


...multiple emptylines ...


phone: "9876735"
name: "doe"

phone: "3434343"
name: "tack"
```

The Desired output lines are:-

```
phone: "3434343" name: "jack"
phone: "9876735" name: "john"

 ...
```

Below is what I wrote to work out

```
cat /tmp/sip_summary2.log | while  read LINE; 
do
echo $LINE | grep '^$' > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
      echo " " >> /tmp/tempsip.log 
    else
      printf "%s " "$LINE" >> /tmp/tempsip.log
    fi
done
```

Are there any better or cleaner alternatives for this?

Comment: I've narrowed down your question somewhat. Don't spam multiple tags for multiple tech stacks please. Ask a separate question for a Python solution (and include your own attempt for that).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`awk` solution:

```
awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1' inputfile
```

Here the default `RS` is changed to blank.  `{$1=$1}` is for record reconstruction and `1` is for printing the record.

Comment: can be further shortened to `awk '$1=$1' RS= file`

Answer (score 4):

Python solution. Read line by line and print with or without newline depending on the prefix:

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
  for l in f:
    l = l.strip()
    if l.startswith("phone:"):
        print(l,end=' ')
    elif l.startswith("name:"):
        print(l)
```

prints:

```
phone: "3434343" name: "jack"
phone: "9876735" name: "john"
phone: "3434343" name: "Mack"
phone: "9876735" name: "doe"
phone: "3434343" name: "tack"
```

Comment: I've removed the Python tag; the alternative would have been to close the question as too broad.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I perfectly understand. Wouldn't have answered if the tag wasn't here.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution based on `Awk` getline() function,

```
awk 'NF{key=$0; getline; print key, $0;}' file
phone: "3434343" name: "jack"
phone: "9876735" name: "john"
phone: "3434343" name: "Mack"
phone: "9876735" name: "doe"
phone: "3434343" name: "tack"
```

i.e. for every non-empty lines, `NF{}`, store the current line in a variable `key`, read the next line which now becomes `$0` and print it.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e '/phone:/{N; /\nname/{s/\n/ /g;p;d}}' -e '/^\s*$/d'
```

(OR)

```
sed -e '/phone:/{N; s/\n\(name:\)\?/ \1/}' -e '/^\s*$/d'
```

**Test:**

```
$ sed -e '/phone:/{N; /\nname/{s/\n/ /g;p;d}}' -e '/^\s*$/d' file
phone: "3434343" name: "jack"
phone: "9876735" name: "john"
phone: "3434343" name: "Mack"
phone: "9876735" name: "doe"
phone: "3434343" name: "tack"
```

Answer (score 1):

`pr` is a good choice for grouping consecutive lines. For example, grouping 10 lines as five columns with `,` as separator

```
$ seq 10 | pr -5ats,
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
```

For given input, pre-processing is also needed to get only non-empty lines

```
$ grep -vx '' ip.txt
phone: "3434343"
name: "jack"
phone: "9876735"
name: "john"
phone: "3434343"
name: "Mack"
phone: "9876735"
name: "doe"
phone: "3434343"
name: "tack"
```

And then use `pr`

```
$ grep -vx '' ip.txt | pr -2ats' '
phone: "3434343" name: "jack"
phone: "9876735" name: "john"
phone: "3434343" name: "Mack"
phone: "9876735" name: "doe"
phone: "3434343" name: "tack"
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk, using content to control `print`ing:

```
$ awk '/^name/{print p, $0}/^phone/{p=$0}' file
phone: "3434343" name: "jack"
phone: "9876735" name: "john"
phone: "3434343" name: "Mack"
```

If `phone`, store line to `p`. If `name` `print` `p` and current record `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `bash` only

```
unset v;
i=0; 
for d in `cat file`; do 
    v[$i]="$d";
    ((++i));
    if [ "$i" -eq 4 ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "${v[*]}";
        i=0;
    fi;
done
```

Another solution using `paste` and `sed`

```
sed '/^$/d' file | paste -d" " - -
```

you get,

```
phone: "3434343" name: "jack"
phone: "9876735" name: "john"
phone: "3434343" name: "Mack"
phone: "9876735" name: "doe"
phone: "3434343" name: "tack"
```